# I keep getting duplicate data in my record

Tags: sql, list, ms-access

I am using MS access.

I tried write SQL code that refer to the tables EMPLOYEE, PROJECT and JOB and return the results as shown in the figure below:

```
PROJ_NAME PROJ_VALUE PROJ_BALANCE EMP-LNAME EMP_FNAME EMP_INITIAL JOB_CODE JOB_DESCRIPTION    JOB_CHG_HOUR
iCEBUTT   800.00     12000        SMITH     ANNE      E           12       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  10
FIREBUTT  810.00     20000        SHEMAN    ANNE      G           15       WATER ENGENEER     12
iCEBTEA   802.00     10000        SIMPSON   ANNE      H           11       NON ENGENEER       11
iCECUBE   890.00     18000        SMITFIELD ANNE      A           19       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  9.5
```

MY CODE

```
SELECT  PROJ_NAME, PROJ_VALUE, PROJ_BALANCE, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL,            JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION, JOB_CHG_HOUR
FROM EMPLOYEE, JOB, PROJECT
WHERE PROJ_VALUE >= 10000;
```

what I got from my code is a lot of duplicate datas.
My result:

```
PROJ_NAME PROJ_VALUE PROJ_BALANCE EMP-LNAME EMP_FNAME EMP_INITIAL JOB_CODE JOB_DESCRIPTION    JOB_CHG_HOUR
iCEBUTT   800.00     12000        SMITH     ANNE      E           12       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  10
iCEBUTT   800.00     12000        SMITH     ANNE      E           12       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  10
iCEBUTT   800.00     12000        SMITH     ANNE      E           12       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  10
iCEBUTT   800.00     12000        SMITH     ANNE      E           12       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  10
FIREBUTT  810.00     20000        SHEMAN    ANNE      G           15       WATER ENGENEER     12
FIREBUTT  810.00     20000        SHEMAN    ANNE      G           15       WATER ENGENEER     12
FIREBUTT  810.00     20000        SHEMAN    ANNE      G           15       WATER ENGENEER     12
FIREBUTT  810.00     20000        SHEMAN    ANNE      G           15       WATER ENGENEER     12
iCEBTEA   802.00     10000        SIMPSON   ANNE      H           11       NON ENGENEER       11
iCEBTEA   802.00     10000        SIMPSON   ANNE      H           11       NON ENGENEER       11
iCEBTEA   802.00     10000        SIMPSON   ANNE      H           11       NON ENGENEER       11
iCECUBE   890.00     18000        SMITFIELD ANNE      A           19       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  9.5
iCECUBE   890.00     18000        SMITFIELD ANNE      A           19       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  9.5
iCECUBE   890.00     18000        SMITFIELD ANNE      A           19       ELECTRIC ENGENEER  9.5
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you shouldn't have any rows. Are you sure this is all your code? The duplication is probably due to missing clauses on your join.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: @2h2h2h I dont think Patrick meant that you need to write out all of your columns, but rather your join syntax is missing the ON clause on your joins.

Comment: Can you give example of few rows of the result? Since your query does not contain join conditions, a Cartesian products are calculated between tables..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the condition for the joins. Now both `employee` and `job` give all records. You have to tell how they relate to the `project` table.

Something like this:

```
SELECT  p.PROJ_NAME, p.PROJ_VALUE, p.PROJ_BALANCE, p.EMP_LNAME, p.EMP_FNAME, p.EMP_INITIAL,            p.JOB_CODE, p.JOB_DESCRIPTION, p.JOB_CHG_HOUR
FROM EMPLOYEE e, JOB j, PROJECT p
WHERE p.job_code = j.job_code /*enter correct fields here*/
AND   p.emp_name = e.emp_name /*enter correct fields here*/
AND   p.PROJ_VALUE >= 805000.00;
```

The field names I used are based on your current query. I hope there are some ID fields you could use instead.

Preferably use real `join`s:

```
SELECT  p.PROJ_NAME, p.PROJ_VALUE, p.PROJ_BALANCE, p.EMP_LNAME, p.EMP_FNAME, p.EMP_INITIAL,            p.JOB_CODE, p.JOB_DESCRIPTION, p.JOB_CHG_HOUR
FROM PROJECT p
JOIN JOB j
ON   p.job_code = j.job_code /*enter correct fields here*/
JOIN EMPLOYEE e
ON   p.emp_name = e.emp_name /*enter correct fields here*/
WHERE p.PROJ_VALUE >= 805000.00;
```

Comment: Uhm I know i am noob, but what is Project p, is it a attribute in the project table?

Comment: `p` is an alias for `project`. It makes your code more readable and will help performance too.

Comment: p is an alias to refer to the Project table

Comment: It said there are two JOB_CODE, What do I need to do now. My JOB_CODE is my PK in JOB table.

Comment: @2h2h2h: See the update. The fields in the select itself are ambiguous so you can fix that with the alias too.

Comment: Sorry but It said Error from clause.

Comment: On which of the two statements? If that the full error message?

Comment: @PatrickHofman how do it feel to slowly realize this question is wasting your valuable time. Seriously OP he has already explained that you are missing join predicates. You should be able to figure out what predicates you need easier than Patrick.

Comment: It is the full message error. But can I use JOIN LEFT statement for this sistuation?

Comment: I am not sure. I just start this one yesterday. but if you so kind you can Show me the code

Comment: What code? It should work. Try to narrow it down piece by piece. Remove one join, check if it works, etc. Then you know the source and we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: but it is not work, It said I miss operator in my code

Comment: Which of the two statements gave you this error and what line does it go to?

Comment: It said Missing operator in the statement of p.job_code = j.job_code and p.emp_name = e.emp_name.

Comment: WELL MATE, tHANKS FOR THE WORK. I CAN DO IT ON MY OWN NOW. HAVE A GOOD NIGHT!

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Cartesian product (or cross join). The valus obtained are not only duplicates but also wrong. To avoid this, you need to use joins in your query.

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE 
JOIN JOB ON EMPLOYEE.JOB_ID = JOB.ID
JOIN PROJECT ON EMPLOYEE.PROJ_ID = PROJECT.ID
WHERE PROJECT.PROJ_VALUE >= 805000.00;
```

Check [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm) for some insight on using SQL joins.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Some preassumption on my part. Edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual duplicate data you are receiving or the structure of the tables, it is hard to answer... but I assume that it is because you aren't limiting the joins of the tables...

Such as

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE e
JOIN Job j on j.JobID = e.JobID
JOIN Project p on p.ProjectID  = e.ProjectID (or j.ProjectID?)
```

You need to limit the data the secondary tables are returning...  as you have it now, the secondary tables will return all.

Outer or inner join used depending on how you have them tied together...

Answer (score -3):

You are using a join on three tables: Employee, Job and Project, but add no join conditions. This creates duplicates. Consider adding conditions like this:

```
SELECT  PROJ_NAME, PROJ_VALUE, PROJ_BALANCE, EMP_LNAME, EMP_FNAME, EMP_INITIAL,                JOB_CODE, JOB_DESCRIPTION, JOB_CHG_HOUR
FROM EMPLOYEE, JOB, PROJECT
WHERE PROJ_VALUE >= 805000.00
AND JOB.EMPLOYEE_ID=EMPLOYEE.ID
AND PROJECT.JOB_ID = JOB.ID;
```

Comment: It said that there are many JOB_CODE, what do I need to do now. My JOB_CODE is my PK in JOB table.

Comment: Do not encourage the use of pre-ansi 92 join syntax!

Comment: @Zane but what if i ***like*** random cartesian products?

Comment: @swasheck you my friend may be looking for BadAdvice.StackExchange.com

Comment: @Zane i thought that stackoverflow.com was an alias that pointed to that site, though.

Comment: @Zane seems a legitimate advice. For Access. I'd prefer the ANSI-89 syntax over the loads of parentheses ;)